Unable to import .xcframework in Swift project after adding to Xcode
I’m trying to add the Amazon Fling SDK .xcframework to my Swift project in Xcode, following the official setup guide. Despite completing all the steps, I still can’t import the framework into my Swift files.
Here’s what I’ve done so far, based on the official instructions from Amazon:
Setting up your Amazon Fling Development Environment for iOS

I downloaded the .xcframework and added it to my Xcode project via File -> Add Files to [MyProject]....

The .xcframework is listed under Link Binary with Libraries in Build Phases.
However, I receive an error saying that "No such module".


Any advice on what else I might be missing would be greatly appreciated!

I don't think that there would be an issue while adding this SDK, I did the same steps & able to import the XCFramework in the project. There might be a case that you have not added the xcframework correctly. You must have to check options while drag & drop the framework.enter image description here

Thanks for your help! The library is now added successfully.
